# Compiling all definitions in the document, but inconsistent formatting in the output

Tags: environments, appendices

I am using the following code to compile a list of all definitions at the end of my notes, sort of like a glossary but automated. However, there is a problem with the way the definitions are formatted in the output: - only the first two definitions have the word 'Definition 4.1' or so in bold, and are left aligned whereas all the following definitions are centre-aligned and have no part in bold. I can't figure out why that is happening or what changes I ought to make.

```
    \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, latexsym}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\usepackage{environ}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defnINN}{Definition}[chapter]
    \makeatletter
    \newtoks\definition@toks
    \newcounter{definitioncount}

    \NewEnviron{defn}[1][]{%
      \@tempswafalse
      \expandafter\catch@definitionlabel\BODY\label\@@nil\@nil
      \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \defnINN
      \else
        \defnINN[#1]%
      \fi
      \if@tempswa
        \refstepcounter{definitioncount}%
        \edef\definition@label{\romannumeral\value{definitioncount}}%
        \label{\definition@label}%
      \fi
      \BODY
      \enddefnINN
      \edef\@tempa{%
        \noexpand\item[Definition\noexpand~\thedefnINN\noexpand~%
        (page\noexpand~\noexpand\pageref{\definition@label})]%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
      }
      \global\definition@toks=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\definition@toks\@tempa}%
    }
    \def\catch@definitionlabel#1\label#2#3\@nil{%
      \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
        % no \label
        \@tempswatrue
      \else
        % \label
        \def\definition@label{#2}%
      \fi

    }
    \def\printdefinitions{%
      \begin{description}\let\label\@gobble
      \the\definition@toks
      \end{description}
    }
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{One}
    \begin{defn}
    A model is said to be a game if it comprises of players. \\
    \end{defn}

    \chapter{two}
    \begin{defn}
     this is chapter two
    \end{defn}

    \chapter{three}
    \section*{three as well}
    \begin{defn}
     \center{this is chapter three}
    \end{defn}

    \chapter*{List of Definitions}
    \printdefinitions
    \end{document}
```

I edited to make an example, but the code seems to be working just fine with this example, I suppose something else in my preamble is thus creating a conflict!

EDIT: If anyone is interested in what caused the problem, I used \center{} in my second definition, causing all others to be centrally aligned in the list at the end.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a minimal example we can compile to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please update your post to include the code that replicates your problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was due to code not in the question and was resolved by the OP as noted in an edit to the question ....

Answer (score 1):

As your MWE compiles without exhibiting your problem it is difficult to troubleshoot your code, but aren't you over-cooking this? The following seems to do what you want but perhaps there are some other features that you want for which you need a different approach:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, latexsym}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\newcommand\definitionList{\relax}
\NewEnviron{defn}[1][\relax]{%
    \ifx#1\relax\relax\Definition\BODY\endDefinition%
    \else\Definition[#1]\BODY\endDefinition%
    \fi%
    %\label{definition\theDefinition}% unneccesary
    \xappto\definitionList{\noexpand\item[Definition~\theDefinition\space (page \thepage)]\BODY}%
}
\newcommand\listofdefinitions{% print list of definitions
      \chapter*{List of Definitions}
      \begin{description}\definitionList\end{description}
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{One}
    \begin{defn}
    A model is said to be a game if it comprises of players.
    \end{defn}

    \chapter{two}
    \begin{defn}
     This is chapter two
    \end{defn}

    \chapter{three}
    \section*{three as well}
    \begin{defn}
     This is chapter three
    \end{defn}

    \listofdefinitions
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

The use of `xappto` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package leads to some simplifications but the main change is the you do not need to use labels,  because the list of definitions is being printed *after* the definitions are created. If you want to add hyperlinks from the list of definitions back to the actual definitions, which I would want, then you do need the labels. The following modification takes care of the hyperlinks:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, latexsym}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\def\Definitionautorefname{Definition}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\definitionList{\relax}
\NewEnviron{defn}[1][\relax]{%
    \ifx#1\relax\relax\Definition\BODY\endDefinition%
    \else\Definition[#1]\BODY\endDefinition%
    \fi%
    \label{definition\theDefinition}
    \xappto\definitionList{%
       \noexpand\item[\noexpand\autoref{definition\theDefinition} (page \thepage)]\BODY%
    }%

\newcommand\listofdefinitions{% print list of definitions
      \chapter*{List of Definitions}
      \begin{description}\definitionList\end{description}
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{One}
    \begin{defn}
    A model is said to be a game if it comprises of players.
    \end{defn}

    \chapter{two}
    \begin{defn}
     This is chapter two
    \end{defn}

    \chapter{three}
    \section*{three as well}
    \begin{defn}
     This is chapter three
    \end{defn}

    \listofdefinitions
\end{document}
```